# Interesting behaviour with infix notation

Tags: scala

One sometimes try to get away from your girlfriend by hiding behind your computer screen. However, I find that Scala is sometimes exactly like my girl...

This prints the intersection between two lists:

```
  val boys = List(Person("John"), Person("Kim"), Person("Joe"), Person("Piet"), Person("Alex"))

  val girls = List(Person("Jana"), Person("Alex"), Person("Sally"), Person("Kim"))

  println("Unisex names: " + boys.intersect(girls))
```

This prints absolutely nothing:

```
  val boys = List(Person("John"), Person("Kim"), Person("Joe"), Person("Piet"), Person("Alex"))

  val girls = List(Person("Jana"), Person("Alex"), Person("Sally"), Person("Kim"))

  println("Unisex names: " + boys intersect girls)
```

There are no compiler warnings and the statement prints absolutely nothing to the console. Could someone please explain gently (I have a hangover), why this is so.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It gets desugared to this:

```
println("Unisex names: ".+(boys).intersect(girls))
```

then according to the `-Xprint:typer` compiler option it gets rewritten like this:

```
println(augmentString("Unisex names: ".+(boys.toString)).intersect[Any](girls))
```

where `augmentString` is an implicit conversion from type `String` to `StringOps`, which provides the `intersect` method.

Comment: Thanks Nikita, but then why doesn't it at least print the intersection of those two strings, which should be: `nisex names List(Person(Jon), Person(K),Pero(),Pr()Al)`

Comment: @JacobusR Sorry, I didn't test it the first time. Turns out the magic is a bit different. See the updates.