# Recommended style for arity-1 call followed by arity-0 call

Tags: scala

Given that the official Scala style guide
http://docs.scala-lang.org/style/method-invocation.html
recommends using infix notation for arity-1 calls and dot notation for arity-0 calls, what's the recommended style for an arity-1 call followed by an arity-0 call?

For example, would this be the recommended way?

```
(bytes map (_.toChar)).mkString
```

Comment: I typically avoid infix unless I'm trying to use something like an operator as opposed to a method. Obviously, there's no sharp dividing line, but to me, `map` doesn't really fit the bill. It seems unequivocally much more like a method call. I do understand how a bunch of functor operations can look pretty when chained infix. What looks really ugly to me is to mix the styles like that in the same level of an expression.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The summary of the style guide is basically: use point-free style whenever it is simple and clear.  Otherwise, don't.  In this case, your options are

```
bytes.map(_.toChar).mkString
(bytes map (_.toChar)).mkString
```

and the former looks simpler and clearer to me, so it wins.

Really long chains are also not very clear in point-free notation

```
foo bar baz qux quux bippy
```

Say what again?

```
foo.bar(baz).qux(quux).bippy
```

Oh, okay.

Be pragmatic.  Point-free style can be clean and elegant.  Good coding style will often lead you to write code that looks nice point-free.  But the point of the syntax is to be clear and avoid errors, so use whichever better accomplishes the goal.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know who wrote this guide, but he definitely seemed biased, and I would advice against following this guide. Infix notation has a lot of pitfalls, which the author doesn't mention, and the benefits of it are questionable at very least. The arguments the author uses are not any less questionable.

The author argues that the following code makes it look like a method `filter` is being called on a function `(_.toUpperCase)`:

```
names.map (_.toUpperCase).filter (_.length > 5)
```

But nobody formats the code like that. The following are the standard practices and they both introduce no ambiguity of such:

```
names.map(_.toUpperCase).filter(_.length > 5)

names.map( _.toUpperCase ).filter( _.length > 5 )
```

### Pitfalls of the infix notation

1. Parameterless methods [cannot be used inside a method calls chain](http://ideone.com/t7bTab).
2. Parameterless methods [cannot be used in the end of a method calls chain](http://ideone.com/AoaqP7), because they grab the terms from the next line.
3. [It does not allow splitting to multiple lines](http://ideone.com/gQSfz9). You'll either have to introduce some [lispy bracketing](http://ideone.com/B4l7wY) or awkardly [place the parameters on the next line](http://ideone.com/5sujnt). Another option is to switch back to the "dot" notation and end up with an [inconsistent style](http://ideone.com/UJZURB).

   All those options can hardly be referred to as increasing the readability.
4. It breeds [misunderstandings like that](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23925713/485115).
5. Finally, it adds a layer of obfuscation of your intent. I.e., a reader has to analyse how the compiler will infer the dots and braces prior to actually comprehending the code.

### Conclusion

The only argument for this notation that I've ever met is that it increases readability. While this argument is questionable itself, I find that it can hardly stand against any of the aforementioned drawbacks of this notation, due to which it often even decreases the readability.

The most consistent and safe standard is to use infix notation only for operators, i.e., methods with names like `+`, `*`, `>>=`.

Comment: I completely disagree with your option. I find it much more readable to see `map` without the "." and `filter` without the "." Please refer me to where this "standard" is?

Comment: @wheaties This readability comes at a cost of inconsistency and potential bugs, which I describe in the updates to my answer. The standard I refer to is the one I've seen in most of the code I've had to deal with in Scala. For the most part the base Scala libraries follow it too.

Comment: That's fine but I still disagree with it. That's the funny part about opinions, isn't it? :P

Comment: @wheaties Well, I've presented arguments, so it's not just an opinion. It would be helpful if you presented some counter-arguments, since you disagree.

Comment: Con 1 is wrong, if you terminate a line with the infix operator you can continue the expression on the following line. It doesn't work well in the REPL, but in compiled code or with `:paste` there are no problems.

Comment: @wingedsubmariner Okay, I'll rephrase: you can't do this in [the naturally expected way](http://ideone.com/gQSfz9). It is true that you can place a method call and parameters on separate lines, but I would say that it by far defeats all the arguments about readability. I've updated the answer to include that.